# AD Groups of one domain/farm( 2013) not showing up on SharePoint(2007) in another domain

Tags: 2007, ad

[image: AD Group]

I have SharePoint 2013 and 2007 environments, i have created test AD groups on 2013 farm and would like that to show up on 2007 farm.
Note - 2013 and 2007 are different domains

SharePoint 2013 Farm - MAS DEV Intarnet Developers(AD Group)

When i go to my 2007 Farm and try to add this AD Group i cant find it, can anybody suggest what might be wrong in here ?

Comment: You said two different domains, is their any trust between domains?

Comment: Yes @WaqasSarwarMCSE i was told there is a trust between the FARMS.Thank You

Comment: between farm is different then between domains. we need a trust between both domains, and also try to change the group type from global to universal then try again

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE we have trust between the domains and i did change the Group type from global to universal and it still doenst show up in my 2007 farm.